# Pure CSS drop down menu with delay issue

Tags: html, css

I found a great CSS solution for a menu with submenu, pure CSS:
link: [Codepen by Phil Hoyt](https://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd)

Now I want a delay on hiding the menu on mouse movements. So that the menu doesn't hide directly when the mouse is off the menu item (for a short time). So I added some CSS, found  [on this page](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/#article-header-id-2), resulting in code below. Previous link exactly explains my issue, but I haven't been able to fix it with the hints.

When you hover the main menu items, the delay of the first item keeps the menu item open, while the mouse is already on the second menu item. See gif below.

How will I be able to fix this? Keeping the delay, but when another menu is open, hiding the menu item instantly.

---

[image]

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s 1s;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty simple, add the transition delay only when you don't hover the menu container (you move the mouse out)

**By the way thanks for inspiration how to solve accidentally hovering out of nested narrow menu items.**

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul:hover ul
{
    transition: 0s;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul:not(:hover) ul
{
    transition: 0.1s 1s;
}
```

(This should do the same)

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    transition: 0.1s 1s;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul:hover ul
{
    transition: 0s;
}
```

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 visibility: hidden;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}
#primary_nav_wrap:not(:hover)  ul
{
    transition: all 0.1s;
    transition-delay:1s;
}
#primary_nav_wrap:hover > ul:not(:hover)
{
    transition: all 0s!important;
    transition-delay:0s!important;
    display:none!important;
}
   
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Whow great!!! There is one glitch! If you hover Menu 1 > Sub menu 4 > Deep menu 1. And then go quickly to Menu 3. You will see that the sub menu still has the delay.

Comment: @Timo002 it took a little fiddling, but this should take care of it (updated snippet)

Comment: @Timo002 BTW thanks for inspiration... Sometimes narrow menu items that disappear after accidentaly hovering out is frustrating... I have never though myself of doing this.

Comment: @Timo002 no pressure - if you are satisfied with answer, please tick is as solution (In case there are no other issues related to your question) - Thanks in advance.

Comment: Corrected: When I hover on `<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">`, and not on a ul / li the whole menu is hidden.

Comment: Here a JSfiddle that shows what I mean. This is my own menu. Hover on the none `li` and you see what happens. https://jsfiddle.net/7v97gago/1/

Comment: @Timo002 that is because your ul height is 0 because of floating elements... add either `> li {
                float: none;
                position: relative;
                display:inline-block;
                }` https://jsfiddle.net/7v97gago/2/ or `&:after{
              content:"";
              display:block;
              clear:both;
            }` to ul https://jsfiddle.net/h2rqr8z1/1/

Comment: nice! I used the second jsfiddle, since this doesn't mess with other rules. Now I have very nice menu, working fine on touch devices as well. The last glitch is keep the main item background highlighted when until the menu is closed. Now when hover is off, menu is still open but highlight on the main menu item is gone.

Comment: Solution is still the same `&:not(:hover) > ul > li{
            transition-delay: 1s;
        }` https://jsfiddle.net/h2rqr8z1/2/